# Accidentally broke aws-auth config map

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I accidentally broke my access to EKS cluster by running the following command: eksctl create iamidentitymapping --cluster eks-ci --region eu-west-2 --profile eks-ci --arn arn:aws:iam::********:role/eks-ci-role --group developers --username test-eks-ci-user

Problem is that the cluster has been created with an assumed role, so I cannot access at all to my cluster to update the aws-auth configmap back to normal.

I also found this answer : [Mistakenly updated configmap aws-auth with rbac & lost access to the cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085639/mistakenly-updated-configmap-aws-auth-with-rbac-lost-access-to-the-cluster)

But unfortunately, I have no pods running with enough permissions to edit the configmap to normal...

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: if you are having complete access to your AWS account you can assume the role with which you created the eks cluster that Role will by default get access to cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can assume the role which created the cluster (cluster creator's role).
Please follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-cli-call-store-saml-credentials/) blog by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the translation done with Google. My English fluency is poor.

If you broke the EKS aws-auth ConfigMap, it is very likely that you will no longer be able to access your cluster without AWS intervention.

I participated in a similar problem and to solve the case I had to rely on support from AWS support.

I created two new IAM roles (one for the cluster and other for the worker nodes) by copying the ones I already had, so I opened a ticket in AWS and asked to replace the roles with these new ones, as well as reset the aws-auth me sending a copy of the definition that was broken.

As I had Business support, the solution of the case took less than 02 hours.

To prevent this issue from happening again, follow this recommendation:
https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/#use-tools-to-make-changes-to-the-aws-auth-configmap